# Is "$:$" so-called Frobenius inner product?

Tags: matrices, notation, terminology, tensor-products, tensors

I see some notation like
\begin{align*}
\int \nabla \mathbf{u} : \nabla \mathbf{v} \; dx
\end{align*}

Here I think the two vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ should be column vectors, i.e. $\mathbf{u} = [u_1,u_2,...,u_n]^T$ and $\mathbf{v} = [v_1,v_2,...,v_n]^T$. Is that right?

So, here $\nabla \mathbf{u}$ will be a Jacobian matrix, and $\nabla \mathbf{v}$ as well. Right?

Then, does the operation $\nabla \mathbf{u} : \nabla \mathbf{v}$ mean the element-wise multiplication such that
\begin{align*}
\nabla \mathbf{u} : \nabla \mathbf{v} &= (\nabla \otimes \mathbf{u}) : (\nabla \otimes \mathbf{v}) \\
&= \left(
\begin{bmatrix}
\nabla_1 \\
\nabla_2 \\
\vdots \\
\nabla_n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 & u_2 & \cdots & u_n
\end{bmatrix} \right) : \left(
\begin{bmatrix}
\nabla_1 \\
\nabla_2 \\
\vdots \\
\nabla_n
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 & v_2 & \cdots & v_n
\end{bmatrix} \right) \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\nabla_1 u_1 \nabla_1 v_1 & \nabla_1 u_2 \nabla_1 v_2 & \cdots & \nabla_1 u_n \nabla_1 v_n \\
\nabla_2 u_1 \nabla_2 v_1 & \nabla_2 u_2 \nabla_2 v_2 & \cdots & \nabla_2 u_n \nabla_2 v_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\nabla_n u_1 \nabla_n v_1 & \nabla_n u_2 \nabla_n v_2 & \cdots & \nabla_n u_n \nabla_n v_n
\end{bmatrix}. 
\end{align*}
Am I right?

I didn't ever see "$:$" before, but I think it is so-called the Frobenius inner product, though its [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product) page doesn't mention this notation.

Comment: You are correct. In some branches of Physics, e.g. Continuum Mechanics, this operation is called the double-dot product or double-contraction product. In the context of matrices, it is sometimes referred to as the inner product or trace product.

Comment: Your expansion uses the elementwise/Hadamard product and produces a **matrix** result. The trace/Frobenius product produces a **scalar** result; it is calculated by **summing** all the terms in the Hadamard result. A colon usually indicates the trace/Frobenius product. The Hadamard product symbol is either $(\circ)$ or $(\odot)$.